# Is there some clever way to write a lua object so that it doubles up as an iterator?

Tags: iterator, lua, syntactic-sugar

Lets say I have some "object" that I've defined elsewhere. Maybe it represents a set of items, but is more complex than a simple table. Whatever it may be, it would be logical to iterate over it.

As such, it has a `iterator` method defined. So I can write this:

```
local myObject = AbstractObject:new()

for obj in myObject:iterator() do
    obj:foo()
end
```

What I'm wondering is if there is some metamethod trickery that I can do, which will allow me to write this:

```
local myObject = AbstractObject:new()

for obj in myObject do
    obj:foo()
end
```

So is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One slight change to your example would make the semantics a lot less painful:

```
local myObject = AbstractObject:new()

for obj in myObject() do
    obj:foo()
end
```

That way, you can use a metatable to define the `__call` metamethod to return `myObject:interator()`, with code that looks something like this in `AbstractObject:new()`:

```
setmetatable(newobject, {__call = function() return newobject:iterator() end})
```

---

Without the iterator construction, you'll be effectively reusing a single iterator for multiple iterations, which means you'll need to keep the iterator state in the object/creation closure, and reset it after it finishes so the next call will restart the iteration again. If you really want to do this, the best solution would really be to write something for the specific iteration implementation, but this would perform the generic iteration:

```
local iterator

--table.pack is planned for 5.2
local pack = table.pack or function(...)
  local t = {...}
  t.n = select('#',...)
  return t
end

--in 5.1 unpack isn't in table
local unpack = table.unpack or unpack

function metamethods.__call(...)
  if not iterator then
    iterator = newobject:iterator()
  end

  local returns = pack(iterator(...))

  if returns[1] == nil then
    --iteration is finished: next call will restart iteration
    iterator = nil
  end
  return unpack(returns, 1, returns.n)
end
```

Again: This should *really* be adjusted to fit your use case.

Comment: That doesn't work. Because that would create a new iterator on each cycle of the loop.

Comment: Ack! Now you've changed your answer! Yes, that does work out slightly better. My main reason for disliking `myObject()` is that forgetting to add the parentheses results in not an error, but an infinite loop!

Comment: @Eric: That sort of problem is why this sort of metamethod trickery is normally frowned upon.

Comment: I've added an example for the exact behavior you mentioned, but again, I *strongly* discourage its use as written.

Comment: **+1** Nice! I can see a potential problem here though: the for loop using the iterator could have a `break` statement, skipping the reset step.

Comment: Well, there's nothing you can do in that case. You'd have the same problem if you were saving the iterator externally (`local iter = myObject:iterator()`) and then using that in multiple `for` loops. This is why stateful iterators are normally constructed in the `for` statement. As has been said a few times now, the design you described is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Right. I thought that might be the case. I guess it just "seemed like a good idea at the time"

Comment: Couldn't you do the initialization of the iterator depending on the arguments of the call method? For the first call it will get passed `nil` as second argument, later the results of the previous call (which will not be `nil`).

Comment: @Paulo: It depends on the iterator. In most cases, that would be a rational adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

The object used after `in` must be a function, which will be called repeatedly by the generic `for` loop.

I'm not sure if you can make a table or user object callable like a function, but even then the problem would be that your object can only have one internal iterator state - i.e. it would not allow multiple iterations over the same object (neither concurrently nor sequentially), unless you are somehow explicitly resetting it.

As answered by Stuart, you could use the `__call` metamethod suitably to return the iterator, but then you would have to write

```
for obj in myObject() do
    obj:foo()
end
```

This is not quite what we want.

Reading a bit more in [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/7.2.html), I see that there are more components used in the for loop: the invariant loop state, and the current value of the control variable, which are passed to the iterator function in each call. If we don't provide them in the `in` expression, they are initialized to `nil`.

Thus, my idea would be to use these values to distinguish the individual calls.

If you can create a `next(element)` function for your collection which returns for each element the next one, the implementation would be simple:

```
metatable.__call = function(_state, _last)
    if(_last == nil) then
       return obj:first()
    else
       return obj:next(_last)
   end
end
```

But often we would not have something like this, then it gets more complicated.

---

I thought about using coroutines here, but these still need a factory method (which we want to avoid). 
It would result in something similar like what Stuart wrote (i.e. saving the iterator state somewhere in the object itself or in some other variable related to the object), and using the parameter and/or the iterators result to decide when to create/clean the iterator object/state.

Nothing won here.